# Using Javascript or jQuery to make a burger submenu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What I want to do looks like this 2 level dropdown menu

[image]

My problems:

- I can't move the X (close) to the left side so it matches what it should be
- I can't make the submenu to work at all since (ulike the first menu) the point from which I control the toggle (menu-item1) disappears (the submenu covers it)

I have accepted my fate that i will have to use js or jQuery, yet my all my tries to understand it or  make it work, mostly using onclick function, are to no result so far.

Can somebody help me with that?

Note that it actually looks much better, but since I removed a lot of stuff to isolate the burger menu it messed up all my margins-paddings so don't worry about the display factors.

You can, obviously, pay no attention to the topest bar, I only inserted it as well because the burger disappeared without it, probably relative spacing to it, but I am quite new to html/css so I could be wrong

```css
.bg {
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 550px;
}

#topestbar {
  display: flex;
}


/* dropdown menu */

#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -70px;
  left: 90%;
  width: 21px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.grey {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -85px 0 0 -50;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 410px;
  height: 45px;
  background: #F8F8F8;
  z-index: 2;
}

#menuToggle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #002868;
}

#menuToggle a:hover {
  color: #BF0A30;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 3.5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transform-origin: 5px 0px;
  z-index: 3;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, 0px);
  background: #002868;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

#menuToggle input:checked~#menu-m {
  visibility: visible;
}

#menu-m {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 310px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: -90px 0 0 -360px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list li,
#menu-m li a,
.user-m {
  color: #002868;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -30px;
}

.flag2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px 0 0 30px;
}

.down-arrow2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 13px 0 0 60px;
}

.user-m {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: -25px 0 -40px 150px;
}

.user-m img {
  margin: -5px 0px 35px -70px;
}

.line {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 410px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0 0px 0 -50px;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.list li a {
  width: 360px;
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.list img {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}


/* ----- dropdown sub-menu ------ */

#dropdown-m {
  position: absolute;
  background: #F8F8F8;
  ;
  width: 340px;
  height: 528px;
  margin: -150px 0 0 -30px;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 5;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.back {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
}

#back-text {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.back img {
  margin: -2 0 0 -35px;
}
```

```html
<header style="background-color: black;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bg">
      <ul id="topestbar">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="./images/clock.png" ; alt="time" width="auto" height="auto" class="clock-image" />
          </a>
          <div class="time">
            <h3>location</h3>
            <p>13:28</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="./images/cloud-snow.png" ; alt="temprature" width="auto" height="auto" class="cloud-image" />
          </a>
          <div class="weather">
            <h3>storm</h3>
            <p>12°C<span style=opacity:0.5;>°F</span></p>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#" class="down-arrow">
            <img src="./images/down.png" ; alt="more languages" width="auto" height="auto" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <nav role="navigation">
        <div id="menuToggle">

          <input id="check" type="checkbox" />

          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>

          <ul id="menu-m">
            <div class="grey">
              <a href="#" class="flag2">
                <img src="./images/flag.png" ; alt="greek" width="auto" height="auto" />
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="down-arrow2">
                <img src="./images/down2.png" ; alt="more languages" width="auto" height="auto" />
              </a>
            </div>
            <li>
              <ul class="user-m">
                <li> <img src="./images/user-m.png" ; alt="user-login" width="auto" height="auto" /></li>
                <li><a id="login-m" href='#'>login</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="line"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <ul class="list">
                <li><a href="#">menu-item1</a></li>
                <li> <img src="./images/right.png" ; alt="more" width="auto" height="auto" /></li>
              </ul>
              <div id="dropdown-m2">
                <ul id="dropdown-m">
                  <ul class="back">
                    <li> <img src="./images/left.png" ; alt="back-arrow" width="auto" height="auto" /></li>
                    <li><a id="back-text " href='#'>back </a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <li><a href="# ">submenu-items</a></li>
                  <li><a href="# ">submenu-items</a></li>
                  <li><a href="# ">submenu-items</a></li>
                  <li><a href="# ">submenu-items</a></li>
                  <li><a href="# ">submenu-items</a></li>
                  <li><a href="# ">submenu-items</a></li>
                  <li><a href="# ">submenu-items</a></li>
                  <li><a href="# ">submenu-items</a></li>
                  <li><a href="# ">submenu-items</a></li>
                  <li><a href="# ">submenu-items</a></li>
                  <li><a href="# ">submenu-items</a></li>
                  <li><a href="# ">submenu-items</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <ul class="list ">
                <li><a href="# ">menu-items</a></li>
                <li> <img src="./images/right.png " ; alt="more " width="auto " height="auto " /></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <ul class="list ">
                <li><a href="# ">menu-items</a></li>
                <li> <img src="./images/right.png " ; alt="more " width="auto " height="auto " /></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <ul class="list ">
                <li><a href="# ">menu-items</a></li>
                <li> <img src="./images/right.png " ; alt="more " width="auto " height="auto " /></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <ul class="list ">
                <li><a href="# ">menu-items</a></li>
                <li> <img src="./images/right.png " ; alt="more " width="auto " height="auto " /></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <ul class="list ">
                <li><a href="# ">menu-items</a></li>
                <li> <img src="./images/right.png " ; alt="more " width="auto " height="auto " /></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <ul class="list ">
                <li><a href="# ">menu-items</a></li>
                <li> <img src="./images/right.png " ; alt="more " width="auto " height="auto " /></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I fixed your HTML. You had a stray `"` on the LI and missed two `</div></div>` I also removed the body tag since it had irrelevant onload code

Comment: thanks, they were left overs from previous changes and fixes :)